# getting error:syntaxError"ESLint(syntax-parse)unexpected string in method

Tags: sapui5

The error raised at the line 4, which is *"sap/m/MessageToast"*, of code

```
sap.ui.define(
    [
        "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
        "sap/m/MessageToast"
    ],
    function(Controller,MessageToast)
    {
        Controller.extend("opensap.myapp.controller.App",
        {
            onShowHello:function()
            {
                MessageToast.show("Hello openSAP!");
            }
       });
    });
```

Comment: Put a comma into the array

Answer (score 1):

It may say the error is on line 4, but that's because a comma is missing on line 3. You need to separate array entries with a comma.